# Style fragment of text in textarea

Tags: jquery

I have a `textarea` containing the text:`"Hello World"`.

Is there a way to change the color of only `"World"` with jquery?

I can get the value I want to edit with the `slice` method:

```
$('textarea').val().slice(6);
```

But how can I apply a css rule or class to only that part of the textarea value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible you would have to use something other than textarea. I would rather answer this with a "it's not possible" rather than leaving it unanswered.

After searching for a few minutes I found an old post on SO with the same question: [How do I have different font colors in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641685/how-do-i-have-different-font-colors-in-a-textarea)

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No problem, it's a shame HTML ancient elements aren't much styleable.